# Could you generate a lot of electricity in space?

Tags: electricity, vacuum, space

I was just thinking about the fact that if you threw a ball or any object out into space where there is no other forces or gasses it would continue on forever, so say you had a turbine and you spun it and that would keep going for a very long time, couldn’t you basically generate infinite electricity?

I have no idea if this question is dumb as I’m only in year 9 and not done a lot on physics in that much depth...

Answer (score 3):

Okay nvm I just realised how the resistance will be from the turbine itself ‍♂️

Comment: Good that you worked it out for yourself. Both the turbine and the attached generator have friction. If you draw any current from the generator, that will add even more resistance. TANSTAAFL ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The eletric energy that is "generated" by the power plants is nothing else than a transfer of the energy from the source (flowing water in the case of hydroeletric plants, wind's kinetics energy for wind turbines and etc.) to the electrons, moving them this way.

The brute amount of electric energy being generated by the turbine is the same (in a ideal case) of the kinetics energy lost. So as you generate eletric energy the turbine spin less and less until it stops. In the ideal case there's also loss of energy by the friction between the moving parts of your system.